# Чим відрізняються «дощуватий», «дощовитий» і «дощистий»

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

З [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> - Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)
>     **Дощува́тий, дощи́стий, дощови́тий** – дождливый.
> - Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)
>     **Дощи́стий, -а, -е** = **Дощуватий.**
>     **Дощови́тий, -а, -е** = **Дощуватий.** Цей місяць увесь дощовитий. Зміев. у.
>     **Дощува́тий, -а, -е.** Дождливый. Дощувате літо. Черк. у.

Не можу зрозуміти, який прикметник коли використовувати. Зі словників скидається на те, що у них у всіх однакове значення.

Answer (score 1):

Грінченко (у наведеній Вами же цитаті) вважає їх синонімами (визначає *дощуватий* і *дощистий* строго через *дощовитий*).

(Хоча мені особисто *дощуватий* асоціюється з *трішки дощовитий* — але я не можу гарантувати, що це правда.)

Ані [«Словник укр. мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl), ані [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) зовсім не містять слів *дощуватий* і *дощистий* — припускаю, ці два слова менш уживані, ніж *дощовитий*.

Comment: Особливо сподобалось оце -  «*дощуватий* асоціюється з *трішки дощовитий*». Дійсно *дощуватий* видається як наче трішки схільний дощити.